# Erorr when connecting to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

My WCF method tries to get some data from database. At the end calls this method:

```
 public override IQueryable<Apartment> GetAll()
    {
        return base.GetAll().Include("Pictures").Include("Infos");
    }
  public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }
```

but it seems error happens when it tries to open connection to database. I'm getting error `The underlying provider failed on Open."`. Can I somehow specify in WCF confg file whch are allowed database to connect or in my project allow WCF to connect to my database. Or there is some other solution?

```
 public Base()
    {
        DataContext = new Context();
        this.DbSet = DataContext.Set<T>();
        DataContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        DataContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

...

```
 public class Context:DbContext
{
      public Context()
         : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
```

Comment: What code do you use to connect to the database? I'm talking about connstrings in web.config, the method you use to read those, how you process them into your DataContext,... DO NOT FORGET: remove any sensitive information like passwords, usernames or ip addresses. Also, is there an inner exception from the provider in that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class partial extension to `Context`. Within that override the constructor to pass in a different connection string (which also needs to be in the config as that name) to base such as

```
public partial class Context
{
    public Context(string targetDBConnection) : base(targetDBConnection) {}
}
```